# Switching the entire project into a previous commit

Tags: git, commit

Consider a project management app that uses git at backend.

The new versions are always created using `git add .` followed by `git commit`.

For evaluation purposes,I want a way to get old version of a project stored in it,in such a way that entire directory contents are reverted to the specified commit.Also,after the evaluation,the contents must be reverted back to the latest version.

How can this be accomplished?

Extra info(might not be necessary):It is a web app for storing academic projects that runs on php,on a remote server,and accessed over a network.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with 'git revert', and really should not be tagged as such.  'revert' in git means to apply a commit that reverses a previously applied commit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is one of the very basic features of `git`: `git checkout`.

```
$ git checkout branch_or_tag_name
```

changes your working directory match that branch or tag.

```
$ git checkout commit_hash
```

makes your current directory reflect the state of your repository when that commit happened. (Careful if you do this, you'll be in "detached head" mode - you shouldn't modify files in that state.)

You can also simply create a branch specifically for this "evaluation" and check it out in one operation:

```
$ git checkout -b evaluation commit_hash
```

When you're done, just checkout the branch you were previously one and the working directory will be updated.

```
$ git checkout master # or whatever your main branch is.
```

(And possibly `git branch -d evaluation` if you don't need that anymore.)

Answer (score 3):

Another solution would be, if you want to have the files in another directory than the working directory, to use `git archive`.

First, create your ref with `git branch` (there aren't really any branches in git, they are called refs, which point to a commit and thus to all the history behind it):

```
git branch oldversion <refspec>
```

See `git help branch` for what a refspec can be (a SHA1, a relative "path" from another refspec etc).

Then, create the directory where you want your old files to be (let's call it `/path/to/oldstuff`) and use git archive from the project directory:

```
git archive oldversion | tar xvf - -C /path/to/oldstuff
```

Example: I use the latest Linux kernel all the time, and have a git repository of it plus Greg KH's stable tree. When I want to have a tree of the latest stable tree to compile it, here is what I do (here, for stable kernel 3.1.6):

```
$ cd /usr/src/linux-git
$ su
# git archive --prefix=linux-3.1.6/ v3.1.6 | tar xvf - -C ../
```

Comment: +1'd for `git archive`; a great git command that doesn't get enough love